# insert string as html when button clicked

Tags: javascript, html

I have the below problem where I am trying to get the code from `appleImg` and `pearImg` to be put into an html element called `middleCell` should a button be clicked and based off a value of an input (`input1`). How can I make this work?

```
         <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                 <input id="input1">
                 <button id="leftButton" onclick="fruitTest();">Enter</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="middleCell">Hello</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <button id= "clearButton" onclick="clearBox();">Clear</button>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

```
var appleImg = "<img src=\"https://codehs.com/uploads/afcd3bf7ea7baf3f7d571c6e24c352af\">";
var pearImg = "<img src=\"https://codehs.com/uploads/e0c442f8c020685fc8016f15c2547f1e\">";


// Add your JavaScript code bel
var middleCell = document.getElementById("middleCell");
function fruitTest(){
    var myInput = document.getElementById("input1");
    var inputValue = myInput.value;
    if (inputValue > 100){
        middleCell.innerHtml = appleImg;
    } else if (inputValue < 0){
        middleCell.innerHtml = pearImg;
    }
} 
function clearBox (){
    middleCell.innerHtml = "";
}
```

I wanted the value of the `middleCell` to show the images based of what was entered. When 101 is entered and button clicked, the `appkle` image should show up.

Also, when clicking clear, the `middleCell` should be clear.

Comment: Why not use an `<img>` element instead of a `<p>` for your middle cell? Then just use JavaScript to set the `.src` of that element? In terms of hiding an element, `.toggleAttribute("hidden")`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You should use `innerHTML` instead of `innerHtml` and also I wouldn't recommend to hardcode element as a string. You can create elements using the corresponding JS function instead. Also, consider using `const` and `let` instead of `var`.

Please let me know if this helps.

```js
const appleImg = "https://codehs.com/uploads/afcd3bf7ea7baf3f7d571c6e24c352af";
const pearImg = "https://codehs.com/uploads/e0c442f8c020685fc8016f15c2547f1e";

const middleCell = document.getElementById('middleCell');
function fruitTest(){
    const myInput = document.getElementById('input1');
    const inputValue = myInput.value;
    const img = document.createElement('img');
    if (inputValue > 100){
       img.src = appleImg;
    } else if (inputValue < 0){
       img.src = pearImg;
    }
    middleCell.innerHTML = '';
    middleCell.appendChild(img);
} 
function clearBox (){
    middleCell.innerHTML = '';
}
```

```html
         <table border="1">
            <tr>
                <td>
                 <input id="input1">
                 <button id="leftButton" onclick="fruitTest();">Enter</button>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <p id="middleCell">Hello</p>
                </td>
                <td>
                 <button id= "clearButton" onclick="clearBox();">Clear</button>   
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

Answer (score -1):

After doing some tests here, I think that you can use the following if you need to keep the text + image:

```
middleCell.insertAdjacentHTML('afterbegin', IMAGE)
```

I like this method cause you can insert the HTML (even if doing this can not be the best option for all the cases :p) in different positions
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML

Instead of doing the

```
 middleCell.innerHtml = ...
```

And to remove the image after clicking on the clear button, one approach should be getting the added image by using `querySelector` (https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
const image = middleCell.querySelector('img')
image.remove()
```

Answer (score -2):

I changed innerHtml to innerHTML. The HTML must be in all caps. That looks like what your problem was.
Plus I added parseInt() around inputValue to make sure it was converted to a number

```
var appleImg = "<img src=\"https://codehs.com/uploads/afcd3bf7ea7baf3f7d571c6e24c352af\">";
var pearImg = "<img src=\"https://codehs.com/uploads/e0c442f8c020685fc8016f15c2547f1e\">";


// Add your JavaScript code bel
var middleCell = document.getElementById("middleCell");
function fruitTest(){
    var myInput = document.getElementById("input1");
    var inputValue = myInput.value;
    if (parseInt(inputValue) > 100){
       middleCell.innerHTML = appleImg;
    } else if (parseInt(inputValue) < 0){
        middleCell.innerHTML = pearImg;
    }
} 
function clearBox (){
    middleCell.innerHTML = "";
}
```